# Sort GraphQL query results in the exact order of input array

Tags: sorting, graphql, operators, sql-order-by

I need to get a number of items from a GraphQL enabled database (no control over its schema) and output them in the exact order called.

For example, if the database holds the items *1,2,3* in that respective order I need to get them as *3,1,2*.

Query:

```
{items(filter: {id: {_in: ["3","1","2"] } } ) {data}}
```

Actual result:

```
{"data": {"items": [{"data": "data-from-1"},{"data": "data-from-2"},{"data": "data-from-3"}]}}
```

Expected result:

```
{"data": {"items": [{"data": "data-from-3"},{"data": "data-from-1"},{"data": "data-from-1"}]}}
```

So I guess that what I'm looking for is a 'meta' operator that relates to other operators rather than the actual query – something like:

`sort:["_in"]` or `orderby:{operator:"_in"}`

...but I didn't manage to find out if such a thing exists or not.

So is it possible in general or maybe in some flavour of GraphQL? Or is it my only choice to prebuild a query with aliases and do it like this:

```
{ 
_3: items(filter:{id: { _eq: "3" }}){data}
_1: items(filter:{id: { _eq: "1" }}){data}
_2: items(filter:{id: { _eq: "2" }}){data}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Which GraphQL client are you using?
If you're using Apollo, and you really don't have access to the schema/resolvers in the server, you can create a local field and resolve it on your own, and so you can manipulate as much as you want.

Reference
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/local-state/managing-state-with-field-policies/#defining

Basically, if you're querying a field like:

```
query {
  someQuery(someFilter: {foo: "bar"}) {
    items {
      data
    }
  }
}
```

You can create a local field and write a `typePolicy` to it. Then you can query something like:

```
query {
  someQuery(someFilter: {foo: "bar"}) {
    items {
      data
    }

    parsedItems @client
  }
}
```

Then you can get data from `ìtems` and resolve `parsedItems` locally as you want.

Comment: Would that be good with performance? Because otherwise, the prebuilding approach seems more at hand, just another function and job done.

Comment: (just with *fetch*). Anyway, I can't tell for sure if I'll have matching data to check against, so  the approach should stay as 'blind' as possible.

Comment: If you're dealing only with the described stuff in the query, it would not be a problem, but depending on the number of items you're fetching, and how those items are structured it may be a problem. However, you said you don't have control over the server, so, there's no other way you can specify how the data should be returned, unless they have a param for you to pass. In other words, as the fields are being resolved in a way and order you don't have control, there's no other way to do this sort.

Comment: Good then, I needed to check that I don't do something trivial in an awkward way / also was not sure if there's a standardized way of telling the server how to return the data.